# Using Regex to search a plaintext file line by line and cherry pick lines based on matches

Tags: python, regex, format

I'm trying to read a plaintext file line by line, cherry pick lines that begin with a pattern of any six digits. Pass those to a list and then write that list row by row to a .csv file.

Here's an example of a line I'm trying to match in the file:

```
**000003**  ANW2248_08_DESOLATE-WASTELAND-3. A9    C        00:55:25:17 00:55:47:12 10:00:00:00 10:00:21:20
```

And here is a link to two images, one showing the above line in context of the rest of the file and the expected result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m10YH.jpg

```
import csv
identifier = re.compile(r'^(\d\d\d\d\d\d)')

matched_line = []
with open('file.edl', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        line = str(line)
        if identifier.search(line) == True:
            matched_line.append(line)
        else: continue

with open('file.csv', 'w') as outputEDL:
    print('Copying EDL contents into .csv file for reformatting...')
    outputEDL.write(str(matched_line))
```

Expected result would be the reader gets to a line, searches using the regex, then if the result of the search finds the series of 6 numbers at the beginning, it appends that entire line to the matched_line list.

What I'm actually getting is, once I write what reader has read to a .csv file, it has only picked out [], so the regex search obviously isn't functioning properly in the way I've written this code. Any tips on how to better form it to achieve what I'm trying to do would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on the characteristics of your example line that qualify it as a match?

Comment: Essentially the regex I'm using matches with the specific pattern of '00:00:00:00' in the timestamps which, in the example read as '00:55:25:17 00:55:47:12' and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more examples of expected input/output would better help with solving this problem but from what I can see you are trying to write each line within a text file that contains a timestamp to a csv. In that case here is some psuedo code that might help you solve your problem as well as a separate regex match function to make your code more readable

```py
    import re
    def match_time(line):
        pattern = re.compile(r'(?:\d+[:]\d+[:]\d+[:]\d+)+')
        result = pattern.findall(line)
        return " ".join(result)
```

This will return a string of the entire timecode if a match is found

```py
    lines = []
    with open('yourfile', 'r') as txtfile:
        with open('yourfile', 'w') as csvfile:
            for line in txtfile:
                res = match_line(line)
                #alternatively you can test if res in line which might be better
                if res != "":
                   lines.append(line)
            for item in lines:
                csvfile.write(line)
```

Opens a text file for reading, if the line contains a timecode, appends the line to a list, then iterates that list and writes the line to the csv.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for commenting. I gave this bit of code a whirl but unfortunately it picked out one line that actually didn't match the regex, and then simply appended that for what looked like the amount of lines there were in the original file. I'm also not 100% on what you mean by alternatively using 'test if res in line', all of the lines in that bit of code seem to be required? Thank you again!